# get the style of the marker I clicked on in mapbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, mapbox

I'm trying to get the style of the icon which I clicked on, in order to get its translate values.
I'm doing this because I want to create a div that will have the same location on the map as the icon who got clicked on.
this is my website so far:
http://www.david-halfon.com/radio/index.html

Basically, each time someone presses the yellow circle, a div should appear around it.

this is the code for events that happen when an icon is being clicked:

```
locale.on('click', function(e) {
    $("#music").attr("src", prop.Url);
    $(".player").show();
    play();
    sendWithAjax(prop.Country, prop.City);
    $("h1").html(prop.Station);
    $("h2").html(prop.Country);
    $("h3").html(prop.City);
    //console.log($(this).css("transform"));
    //console.log($(this).attr("style"));

    console.log($(this));

    setTimeout(function(){ $("h4").html(globalVar);}, 500);

    $(".plusB").show();
    $(".shareB").show();

    map1.setView(locale.getLatLng(), 4);
    playNow = prop.Station;
    playNowCountry = prop.Country
    playNowCity = prop.City;

});
```

The comments are what I have tried to do so far but it does'nt seems to work.

When I'm trying to consloe.log(this) I get 'undefined'.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you don't get the expected `$(this).css(...)` informations is that `this` is not a regular DOM object, as it clearly appears using Firebug:

[image]

The `<img>` you want to get style from is contained in the `_icon` member of this object, so you can use e.g.:

```
console.log($(this._icon).css('transform'));
console.log($(this._icon).attr('style'));
// and so on
```

This way (tested using Firebug on your website), it works fine.

BTW, I couldn't figure out why the click event targets this object rather than the `<img>`...

BTW again, this website is a great idea: cool!

Comment: It works! thank you so much! and thanks again for the kind words :)

Comment: I have a followup question, I'm trying to set up a div with the the translate values as one of the icons but it does not seems to work. this is the div: .trans{
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(353px, -91px, 0px);
  z-index: 1000;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}

Comment: well I changed it to a 2d transform and it appears on the icon but it does not stick to it and move along it as I drag the map or change the zoom. As I said before, all I want to do is just stick a div to an Icon which got clicked on. Do you might have a better solution?

Comment: A better solution? From what I currently know I can't say anything. If I correctly understand: now you can get styles from the icon as you planned, then you create a new `<div>` and affect those properties to it, but it doesn't looks exactly as you want. So this is a distinct, CSS/HTML problem. I suggest you open a new question for that, with a detail example (HTML + CSS) of merely one icon and its associated `<div>`. This way it will be more easy to look at this issue.